# MobileFirst 8 and ionic v.1.x application breaks when started on Android 4.4 (release version)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an application developed with ionic v.1.x and it is integrated with Mobile First 8.

When I install the debug version, it is all OK, but I generated the released version, install it and it crashes.

I have the following error:

```
Process: {APP_ID}, PID: 20565
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.ibm.MFPApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on a.a.f.a@42a0f068, sslSocketFactory is class com.worklight.wlclient.f
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4715)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on a.a.f.a@42a0f068, sslSocketFactory is class com.worklight.wlclient.f
    at a.v$a.a(SourceFile:599)
    at com.worklight.wlclient.c.<init>(SourceFile:76)
    at com.worklight.wlclient.c.a(SourceFile:246)
    at com.worklight.wlclient.a.f.a(SourceFile:181)
    at com.worklight.common.a.a(SourceFile:545)
    at com.worklight.androidgap.b.a.<init>(SourceFile:54)
    at com.worklight.androidgap.b.a.a(SourceFile:85)
    at com.ibm.MFPApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:21)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4712)
    ... 10 more
Force finishing activity {APP_ID}/.MainActivity
```

I saw that another guy had the same problem, but his solution was install 6.2 Cordova version... I tried that and I get the following error:

```
Error: cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below rules in your proguard-project.txt or proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
   private  javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory delegate;
}
```

For more info :

[Obfuscating Android code using Proguard in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/09/19/mfp-80-obfuscating-android-code-with-proguard/)